# Destroying a project in TFS 2008 that's related to another project

Tags: tfs

We're running TFS 2008 SP1, which has been upgraded all way from TFS 2005 Beta.

Since the old 2005 days we've had this project, lets call it `Project A`, that we now want to get rid of/destroy. However, this certain folders from this project have been branched off onto another project, `Project B`, that's currently in use and we definitely don't want to impact it.

So my question is, **if we destroy `Project A` can it have a domino effect and destroy stuff in `Project B`** or have any other adverse affect that we might not have considered?

I've done some testing in test environments for this and it seems to be fine but since we have no users in the test environment I thought it would a good idea to check with the experts out there before we do this in Production!

Also, is there any way of getting a fairly accurate or just a ball-park figure of the size of a Team Project within TFS 2008 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We also have a database from the "beginning of time". I haven't seen any domino effects when doing that, but do have the sql and tfs patches in order for e.g. the "destroy isn't executed in transaction bug".

Comment: thanks, I don't think it should be an issue either, just want to get some advice from others who've tried it.